# How to get the numeric part from a string using T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following string.

```
Input
--------------
2030031469-NAI
```

To get the numeric part, I am using the following script

```
declare @str varchar(50)= '2030031469-NAI'

Select 
    @str
    ,SUBSTRING(@str, 1,  NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-', @str) - 1, -1))
        ,Left(@str,PATINDEX('%-%',@str)-1)
```

to get the following output

```
Output: 
----------
2030031469
```

Is there any other easy/elegant way of doing the same?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
select left(@str, patindex('%[^0-9]%', @str+'.') - 1)
```

Comment: didn't work with xxx-2030031469.  It will be better if it can be more generic to handle all cases.

Comment: This answer is elegant and works well, but not in general cases like mine, for instance when you have casting issues to (big)int. Then the general function which Maddy suggested is best.

Answer (score 10):

In case your string start with alphabet and end with number like *ERT-123*

you can use this query:

```
 (select  substring(@str,patindex('%[0-9]%', @str),len(@str)))
```

Answer (score 7):

Please check with this, i used in my project for extracting phone numbers

```
 CREATE Function [dbo].[RemoveNonNumericCharacters](@Temp VarChar(1000))
    Returns VarChar(1000)
    AS
    Begin

        While PatIndex('%[^0-9]%', @Temp) > 0
            Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex('%[^0-9]%', @Temp), 1, '')

        Return @TEmp
    End
```

Comment: i found in this blog http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/sql-server-extracting-data-again  This is really good one

Answer (score 2):

To extract number from an unformatted string

```
DECLARE @Text NVARCHAR(100)= 'extract only 23124R integer @#%%'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Text, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@Text), PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',SUBSTRING(@Text, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@Text), LEN(@Text)))-1) [ONLY_INT]
```

Comment: this fails on null string

Comment: i think its a good practice to check variable first and then perform any kind of operation on it. Atleasst thats what I do.