# SQL query: how to convert varchar to signed integer for SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I got a column called panel no

```
panel no
--------
1
10
1A
2A
6
...
```

I would like to have the order like

```
panel no
--------
1
1A
2A
6
10
```

I try "order by cast(panel no as signed)" and it works for mysql but not in SQL Server 2000.

what can I do?

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question (i.e. mysql)

Comment: `1A` is not an integer so you can't just cast that to an int.  What is the exact code you are trying in SQL Server?

Comment: The accepted solution of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443462/how-to-get-the-numeric-part-from-a-string-using-t-sql should work with SQL Server 2000 too. CAST the result.

Comment: I send the query:
"SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE columnA = 'abc' ORDER BY CAST('panel no' AS SIGNED)
"signed" is pointed out as an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could adapt the solution of [How to get the numeric part from a string using T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443462/how-to-get-the-numeric-part-from-a-string-using-t-sql) to your needs:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    TableA
WHERE
    columnA = 'abc'
ORDER BY
    CAST(LEFT([panel no], patindex('%[^0-9]%', [panel no] + '.') - 1) AS INT);
```

Please note that the column name `panel no` contains a blank, so it's got to be quoted according the rules of T-SQL.

See this [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/580d5a/1).
This solution is compatible with SQL Server 2000.