# Get substring until a specific character starting from right to left SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a string column where I need to find the substring until the first '-' is found.

Example column ELOT-IGS-2. I need to get "2" as output.
These columns come from a table so I cannot declare the variable as a fixed string.

I tried `LOCATE`, `SUBSTRING_INDEX` but none are build in functions.

I also tried `RIGHT(ID_BETSLIP,CHARINDEX('-',ID_BETSLIP)-1)` but this does not work when I have 2 times "-"

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Check this [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667251/query-to-get-only-numbers-from-a-string) or this [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443462/how-to-get-the-numeric-part-from-a-string-using-t-sql)

Comment: Can I declare a varibale that comes from a column in a table?

Answer (score 4):

```
select RIGHT(<your Field>, CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(<your Field>))-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @t varchar(20) = 'ELOT-IGS-2'
select REVERSE(SUBSTRING(reverse(@t),0,CHARINDEX ('-',REVERSE(@t))))
```

Comment: Almost man! I get for column PIK3-99701 as output "10799". Any way to fix this?

Comment: Igor posted something which worked but deleted his post.SUBSTRING(ID_BETSLIP, LEN(ID_BETSLIP) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(ID_BETSLIP))+2, len(ID_BETSLIP)) as TEST

Answer (score 0):

1. Based on @mohan111's solution you can add `REVERSE` in order to get what you need

   ```sql
   DECLARE @t varchar(20) = 'ELOT-IGS-2'
   select REVERSE(SUBSTRING(reverse(@t),0,CHARINDEX ('-',REVERSE(@t))))
   ```

   You should have done this yourself, once you got @mohan111's solution! For your own improvement you can not ask for everything :-( Once you got a solution that is almost what you need, it is time to try to improve it yourself. Please check [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx), and every time that you need to parse a string, START HERE :-) Try to go over the functions and maybe you will find the solution.
2. The `REVERSE` query and most string parsing function are not good solution in SQL Server, and in most cases you are better to do this using SQLCLR function.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest would be

```
select SUBSTRING(reverse(ELOT-IGS-2),0,charindex('-',reverse(ELOT-IGS-2)))
```