# extract all numbers from start of string?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table which contains some bad data I am trying to clean up.

An example of the fields is below

```
36234735HAN876

2342JOE9823

554444PUT003
```

What I want to do is remove all the numeric characters before the first alphabetical character so it would look like the below:

```
HAN876

JOE9823

PUT003
```

What would be the best way to achieve this? I have used the below method but this can only be used to extract ALL numeric from the string, not the ones before the alphabetical characters

[How to get the numeric part from a string using T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443462/how-to-get-the-numeric-part-from-a-string-using-t-sql)

Answer (score 1):

Use `PATINDEX` to find the first non-numeric character (or first alpha character, depending on the logic) and `STUFF` to remove them:

```sql
SELECT STUFF(V.YourString,1,ISNULL(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',V.YourString),0)-1,0),'')
FROM (VALUES('36234735HAN876'),
            ('2342JOE9823'),
            ('554444PUT003'),
            ('ABC123'))V(YourString)
```

If the logic is the first alpha character, instead of the first non-numeric, then the pattern would be `[A-z]`.

The `NULLIF` and `ISNULL` are in there for when/if the string starts with a alpha/non-numeric and thus doesn't cause `STUFF` to error due to the 3rd parameter being `-1`. The is demonstrated with the additional example I put into the sample data (`'ABC123'`).

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this using `PATINDEX` to locate the first position of an alphabetical character in the string, and then use `SUBSTRING` to only return the characters after that position:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (val VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('36234735HAN876'), ('2342JOE9823'), ('554444PUT003'), ('TEST1234');

SELECT  val,
        SUBSTRING(val, PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%', val), LEN(val)) AS output
  FROM  #temp;

DROP TABLE #temp;
```

Outputs:

```
val             output
36234735HAN876  HAN876
2342JOE9823     JOE9823
554444PUT003    PUT003
TEST1234        TEST1234
```

Note that I have created a temporary table with a column named `val`.  You should change this to work with whatever the actual column is called.

About case sensitivity: If you are using a *non-case sensitive* collation this will work without issue.  If your collation is *case sensitive* then you may need to alter the pattern being matched to cater for upper- and lower-case letters.